# Azure Logic App - import a csv file to a sql server table in Azure

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a CSV file on my onedrive that i want to import into a sql database in azure. 
How do i import the csv file using the logic app?
I have not found anything useful on the web to help me do this.

Can anyone provide any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to this [blog](http://blogs.recneps.org/post/Using-Azure-Logic-Apps-to-Import-CSV-to-SQL-Server), it post the detailed process about to insert CSV data in to SQL server.

The main idea about this blog is convert a CSV file into a flat file then upload the flat file to SQL database.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: I looked through this blog before. I was hoping for something slightly more easier (ie like the flat file connector in SSIS that you can map to a sql table).
i created an xml schema to try and map the csv output but was having problems linking that to the integration account.

Comment: @Mr Paul, I searched a lot, mostly you have to import flat file with other services. If you want to use Integration Account you could refer to this blog.https://pellitterisbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/upload-flat-file-on-azure-sql-database-using-azure-logic-app/ But this process is heavy.

Comment: This blog provides a way using Blob storage to import, and it's more easier, you could have a try.https://marczak.io/posts/azure-loading-csv-to-sql/

Comment: @Mr Paul and read from official doc, I this the easiest way to import is use the bcp tool.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-load-from-csv-with-bcp

Comment: Bcp tool looks promising.
How can that be used in the logic app?

Comment: @Mr Paul BCP is a local tool, if you want to use it in logic app, I have to say no.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback George 

Comment: @Mr Paul, if this could help you, you could mark it as answer. Thanks.